# android multitouch emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, multi-touch

Ok, so after they released android tools r18 google said they added support for multitouch in the emulator as well as sensor stuff.. however I haven't made the multitouch work eventough I made the sensor thing work and is well.. the same but in another port forwarding, moreover the sensor thing only worked once since I tried to make it work again and it didnt work at all.
here is the site:
http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation
nevertheless, they said they were fixing the port forwarding stuff in R19 and I have the R19 installed..
so my question is, anyone have made this work? if so, how do I do it?? (step by step if possible please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation (on the link you posted) says that sensor and multi touch has experimental support, so I don't think you can rely on it working.

Comment: yeah seems that they are still working on it according to Tor Norbye who was kind enough mention this.